# How would I get the current mouse coordinates in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, mouse

I need to get the current mouse coordinates in bash and xdotool doesn't seem to be working for me. How would I do this?

Comment: From where? An X server? Curses? ...

Comment: What error does `xdotool getmouselocation` report?  Debugging that may be easier than coming up with an alternative.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

To avoid all the sed/awk/cut stuff, you can use

```
xdotool getmouselocation --shell
```

In particular,

```
eval $(xdotool getmouselocation --shell)
```

will put the position into shell variables `X`, `Y` and `SCREEN`. After that,

```
echo $X $Y
```

will give a snippet ready for a later `xdotool mousemove` or any other use.

---

My extra for sequential clicking into a few positions is a file positions.txt (given by a few eval/echo runs):

```
123 13
423 243
232 989
```

And the code that uses it is:

```
while read line; do
     X=`echo $line| cut -c1-3`; 
     Y=`echo $line| cut -c4-7`;
     xdotool mousemove --sync $((  0.5 + $X )) $(( 0.5 + $Y ));
     xdotool click 1
done < positions.txt
```

If there is no need to scale pixels (unlike my case), it could be a simple

```
while read line; do
     xdotool mousemove --sync $line;
     xdotool click 1
done < positions.txt
```

Comment: Now the command also outputs WINDOW=... , which seems to solve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34207981/how-do-you-get-window-id-for-xdotool-automatically

Answer (score 34):

Try this out:

```
# Real time mouse position.
watch -t -n 0.0001 xdotool getmouselocation
```

This will show your mouse location at "x" and "y" in real time as you move it. You can save your coordinates into a file for later referencing or to use in a script to automate those mouse movements in the following way:

```
# Save real time mouse coordinates to file.
while true; do xdotool getmouselocation | sed -e 's/ screen:0 window:[^ ]*//g' >> coordinates.txt; done
```

This^ will record *only* mouse coordinates into coordinates.txt. You can use each line in a script if you want to repeat the actions taken while recording. A simple `ctrl+c` will do for ending the recording session.

This is just a small sample of how awesome and practical `xdotool` can be for AFK automation and other things. Even custom bots :D

(Edit)

If you need to strip away the `x:` and `y:` from the `sed` command, you can add the logical OR `|`, while using the `-E` option for extended regex, operator as follows:

`xdotool getmouselocation | sed -E "s/ screen:0 window:[^ ]*|x:|y://g"`

And if you want to use redirection and command substitution for a more compact command, you can use the following rather than a pipe:

`sed -E 's/ screen:0 window:[^ ]*|x:|y://g' <<< $(xdotool getmouselocation)`

As a disclaimer, the sed regex is written for GNU sed and may not work the same across different platforms or sed versions.

Comment: Thanks. Can you further strip `x:` and `y:` away from coordinates.txt? How would you read them back and replay?

Comment: Yeah sure. I edited the answer to reflect your request.

Answer (score 4):

What you meant by `xdotool` not working?

What's the output of

```
xdotool getmouselocation
```

Anyway, if you can compile a `C` program: http://dzen.geekmode.org/dwiki/doku.php?id=misc:xget-mouse-position

Regarding your comment below, you wrote you get:

```
Warning: XTEST extension unavailable on '(null)'. Some functionality may be disabled; See 'man xdotool' for more info. x:654 y:453 screen:0 window:1665
```

I assume (in front of Windows XP) that you get it on two lines like:

```
Warning: XTEST extension unavailable on '(null)'. Some functionality may be disabled; See 'man xdotool' for more info. 
x:654 y:453 screen:0 window:1665
```

If that's the case, you should redirect `STDERR` like:

```
xdotool getmouselocation 2>/dev/null
```

That would skip the warning.

If your only input is the cursos positon line then piping that to `sed` will give you the coordinates like this:

```
xdotool getmouselocation 2>/dev/null | \
sed 's/x:\([0-9]\+\)[ \t]y:\([0-9]\+\)[ \t].*/\1;\2/'
# OUTPUT should by something like:  "654;453"
```

If you want to use the coordinates (with `bash`):

```
export COORDINS=`xdotool getmouselocation 2>/dev/null | sed 's/x:\([0-9]\+\)[ \t]y:\([0-9]\+\)[ \t].*/\1;\2/'`
export XPOS=${COORDINS/;*/}
export YPOS=${COORDINS/*;/}
```

HTH

Comment: I get Warning: XTEST extension unavailable on '(null)'. Some functionality may be disabled; See 'man xdotool' for more info.
x:654 y:453 screen:0 window:1665

Comment: How would I awk/grep/sed that?

Comment: Thanks! Can I set each X and Y to individual variable? Again, how would I sed that?

Comment: new error `$ xdotool getmouselocation 2>/dev/null`

`x:720 y:439 screen:0 window:1665`

Comment: Sorry could you specify your problem properly?

Comment: The outputted coordinates do not change based on mouse movement

Comment: The coordinates change every time you run the export commands. Not automatically.

Comment: No, I'm talking about actually typing the command in terminal. It does not change.

Comment: So you had typed all three `export ...` commands, then did something like: `echo $XPOS $YPOS` then moved your cursor to a different position then  reissued those `export ...` commands and the `echo ...` afterwards, and it did not changed? IMO that can't happen. Could you please paste your terminal lines to some pastebin service like https://gist.github.com/ and provide a link to see it?

Comment: O_O All I am saying is I typed `xdotool getmouselocation 2>/dev/null` in ONE line. I didn't type it line by line. The actual command is not working.

Comment: I just said. The value of X: and Y: do not change at all and are always `x:720 y:439 screen:0 window:1665`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5861/discussion-between-t3hcakeman-and-zsolt-botykai)

Comment: Sorry but I'm rarely available for chat. Please do the previously mentioned terminal commands, and paste the output somewhere and link it to here.

Comment: The mouse coordinates do not change

Answer (score 3):

If you're using xterm, you can issue an escape sequence `ESC [ ? 9 h` which will make xterm send an escape sequence to the controlling program (i.e., bash) when you click with the mouse.  I don't know if other terminal emulators have similar functionality.

Info on mouse tracking in xterm is at http://www.xfree86.org/current/ctlseqs.html#Mouse Tracking

Comment: It would be handy to mention that `ESC [ ? 9 l` should get xterm out of this mode, so that your mouse works the way it's supposed to again.  :)

Answer (score 1):

`I get Warning: XTEST extension unavailable on '(null)'. Some functionality may be disabled; See 'man xdotool' for more info. x:654 y:453 screen:0 window:1665`

So it IS working for you.  You just need to parse the ouput of the command.  You can use the sed script zsolt posted above, or a variety of other options:

```
  xdotool getmouselocation 2>/dev/null | cut -d\  -f1,2 -
  // returns something like "x:2931 y:489"
```

or

```
  xdotool getmouselocation 2>/dev/null \
   | awk 'BEGIN{RS=" ";ORS=RS} {split($0,a,":");} a[1]~/^[xy]$/{print a[2];}'
  // returns something like "2931 489 "
```

or

```
  xdotool getmouselocation 2>/dev/null | sed 's/ sc.*//; s/.://g; s/ /x/'
  // returns something like "2931x489"
```

Plenty of ways to skin this cat.