# how do you get window ID for xdotool automatically

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, ps, xdotool

I am trying to automate testing forms that selenium would take too long (javascript heavy modern forms), and I want to use xdotool and get window IDs. I see you can call `xdotool selectwindow` and click it, but then you have to click it each time. I want to tell it "for google chrome windows where the tab title is x, do y"

I got the window ID here:

```
cchilders@cchilders-Dell-Precision-M3800:~$ xdotool selectwindow
65011713
```

This is for chrome itself, each tab gets the same value when clicked. So I expected to find that in ps or a window manager, but no:

```
cchilders@cchilders-Dell-Precision-M3800:~$ wmctrl -l
0x03a00001  0 cchilders-Dell-Precision-M3800 views.py - /home/cchilders/work_projects - Atom
0x03a00048  0 cchilders-Dell-Precision-M3800 pip_freeze_update.py - /home/cchilders/scripts - Atom
0x03a000bc  0 cchilders-Dell-Precision-M3800 urls.py - /home/cchilders/work_projects - Atom
```

nor does ps work:

```
(clientsite)cchilders@cchilders-Dell-Precision-M3800:~$ ps -alx
F   UID   PID  PPID PRI  NI    VSZ   RSS WCHAN  STAT TTY        TIME COMMAND
4     0     1     0  20   0 185188  5752 ep_pol Ss   ?          0:06 /sbin/init splash
1     0     2     0  20   0      0     0 kthrea S    ?          0:00 [kthreadd]
1     0     3     2  20   0      0     0 smpboo S    ?          0:02 [ksoftirqd/0]
1     0     5     2   0 -20      0     0 worker S<   ?          0:00 [kworker/0:0H]
1     0     7     2  20   0      0     0 rcu_gp S    ?          1:10 [rcu_sched]
1     0     8     2  20   0      0     0 rcu_gp S    ?          0:00 [rcu_bh]
...etc...
```

nowhere does 65011713 show up. Xdotool is a great tool, but the window manipulation expects you to know a lot about the windows, and from what I remember of using it before, the `WINDOW COMMANDS` section of https://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool.xhtml#window_commands has a lot of ways to find a window you know a lot about, but not much in the way of automating getting that window info. How can I determine the window ID (the format xdotool wants) automatically, say by feeding a script the beginning portion of a URL? Thank you

You can look for Google Chrome in the wmtrl:

```
(scripts)cchilders@cchilders-Dell-Precision-M3800:~/scripts/bash$ wmctrl -l
0x03e00001  0 cchilders-Dell-Precision-M3800 Edit - Stack Overflow - Google Chrome
...
```

and grab the first number separated by space to int:

```
In [13]: int("0x03e00001", 16)
Out[13]: 65011713
```

The 16 flag in int tells it expect hexadecimal

```
In [14]: int("0x03e00001")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-96517b980767> in <module>()
----> 1 int("0x03e00001")

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0x03e00001'
```

Comment: `65011713` is a binary value. The values returned from `wmctrl` are hex values. You'll need to convert to have them match (though none of those three do but then I don't see `chrome` in that list at all). Nothing in `ps` is at all relevant here though. If you can't get individual window IDs for the tabs though (and you may not be able to) then you likely can't target a tab specifically (or necessarily even **see** the tabs with `xdotool` in the first place). (It might be worth looking at the output from `xwininfo -tree` to see if you can find what you are looking for there.)

Comment: yes, that's correct, it's a hassle but inting it solves it

Comment: phrase yours as a question if you want me pick it. and I almost lol'ed my spleen inside out at dude voting to close something this specific. <3 SO

Comment: Did you just update your question with the answer you worked out for yourself?

Comment: ya that's a summary, but it's your answer. if you add an answer I'll pick it

Comment: With selenium you can switch between tabs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729265/switch-tabs-using-selenium-webdriver

Comment: awesome, thanks funivan

Comment: Nowadays (xdotool version 3.20151124.1) it seems you can just do `xdotool getmouselocation --shell` while hovering the window you need to work on: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13907499/1333493

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `awk` to extract the ID from the output of `wmctrl -l`.

For example:

```
wmctrl -l | awk '/Google Chrome/ {print $1}'
```

`xdotool` will likely take that hex IDs just fine but if it can't you can convert that to the decimal representation with `strtonum`:

```
wmctrl -l | awk '/Google Chrome/ {print strtonum($1)}'
```

How you match *just* the window you want from the output in `awk` is up to you and your requirements.

It is probably worth noting that `xdotool` also appears to have a `search` command which takes all sorts of specifiers and patterns that you can use to get the window ID of windows you want to operate on. (It even supports a stack of matches that it supports a special format of "window ID" to operate on directly for "chained commands".)

Answer (score 7):

You can find a window with xdotool by name, window class, etc. To search for a window by name with, use:

```
xdotool search --name 'My Window Name'
```

This will print the decimal window id to stdout. The --name flag matches the part or all of the window name. In a browser, that generally includes the current tab name. xdotool can also return the corresponding pid like this:

```
xdotool search --name 'My Window Title' getwindowpid
```

He is an example of sending a series of keypresses and mouseclicks to a window.

```
# Find window with title containing 'My Window Title, activate it,
# move the mouse to coordinates 200x400, left click, then press F5
xdotool search --name 'My Window Title' windowactivate mousemove 200 400 click 1 key F5
# Store window id of the active window
WINDOW_ID=$(xdotool getactivewindow)
# Type a series of characters into the window
xdotool type "this text is being typed into window" --window $A
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a linux system and are using x-display manager, the command `xwininfo` to get window information may work for you.

You can run or script the command `xwininfo -root -tree` and get a detailed and organized output of the xwindows system and the window IDs. You can see how I have used the `xwininfo` output in a small bot I created for runescape. I store the hexidecimal ID of the window title and then convert it to binary using `printf %i` and the hex of the window I am interested in. From there, I can script `xdotool` to do whatever I want in or with the window by making it the active window and moving the mouse to it using `xdotool`.

[image]

So the steps for this method are:

1. Get the window information using `xwininfo -root -tree`.
2. Store the window ID that you are interested in.
   (There may be multiple listings of the window name with different
    hex IDs and you will have to know the parent hex ID which is
    usually the first listed and commonly outlines the child processes in
    a sub-tree.)
3. Convert the window hex ID into binary so `xdotool` can recognize it.
4. Use the `windowactivate` option with `xdotool` in order to get`xdotool`
   to interact with the correct window.
5. Perform whatever next steps you wish.

So it's really quite simple, although a bit time-consuming at first, but once you develop your own method for storing the parent window's hex ID, the rest can be easily automated and no worries arise. If you have trouble determining which hex ID belongs to the parent window, there are ways of checking for parent vs child processes but I don't know if you want to go into all of that. Just comment if you want me to include that information.

I hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

@Yokai apparently gnome doesn't support xdotool

> $ xdotool windowactivate "$window_ID_decimal"

Your windowmanager claims not to support _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW, so the attempt to activate the window was aborted.
xdo_activate_window on window:######## reported an error

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33882247)